# How to skip/consume/swallow a value after tapped into it?

Tags: rxjs

I am trying to achieve something like below

```
from([1,2,3,4]).pipe(
  Filter(v=> v % 2 === 0), 
  Tap( () => call server for even number only), 
  Swallow it, don't emit
).subscribe(()=>{log my odd numbers})
```

I know I can use  `filter( () => false)` but was wondering if there is a better solution to it? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "Swallow it, don't pass on"? From your example I understand that `filter` passes 2 elements out of the source Observable (by the way you should use `from` function with an array not `of`) and then, for each element, calls a remote service. But I do not understand what you should do with the results of these remote calls.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean? Swallow what? Based on what? Filter accepts/rejects values based on a predicate, if you want a better solution, what criteria would you prefer?

If you want to swallow everything, that's not functionally much different from terminating your Observable:

```js
of([1,2,3,4]).pipe(
  filter(v=> v % 2 === 0)
).subscribe(() => call server here);
```

Though I would expect an error as you can't use `%` on arrays. Though this should work:

```js
from([1,2,3,4]).pipe(
  filter(v=> v % 2 === 0)
).subscribe(() => call server here);
```

or

```js
of([1,2,3,4]).pipe(
  filter(v=> v.length % 2 === 0)
).subscribe(() => call server here);
```

#### Higher-order operators

If your server call is an observable-like object (promise, array, observable, ect), then you can use the higher-order operators like mergeMap, switchMap, concatMap, ect. In this case, you're not 'swallowing' a value so much as transforming (mapping) it into your call.

This also means whatever value your `call server observable` emits still gets passed forward. This really is a stream transformation rather than filtering/swallowing values.

```js
from([1,2,3,4]).pipe(
  filter(v=> v % 2 === 0),
  concatMap(v => call server observable)
);
```

## Update

#### Helper Function

```js
/****
 * Pipeable Operator:
 * Takes arrays emitted by the source and spaces out their
 * values by the given interval time in milliseconds
 ****/
function intervalArray<T>(intervalTime = 1000): OperatorFunction<T[], T> {
  return pipe(
    concatMap((v: T[]) =>
      concat(
        ...v.map((value: T) =>
          EMPTY.pipe(
            delay(intervalTime),
            startWith(value)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );
}
```

#### Mocking a hot observerable emitting values overtime:

```js
const source = of([1,2,3,4,5]).pipe(
  intervalArray(250), 
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

#### Solution

Here is how I might implement your question for such an observable. The simplest thing to do is to just subscribe to your observable twice:

```js
source.pipe(
  filter(v => v % 2 === 0),
  concatMap(evenNumber => this.serviceCall(evenNumber))
).subscribe(/* serviceCallResult => Do Nothing */);

source.pipe(
  filter(v => v % 2 !== 0)
).subscribe(oddNumber => console.log(
  "I got an odd Number: ", 
  oddNumber
));
```